# Control onClick function

Tags: javascript, html

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <style type='text/css'>
            span {
                text-decoration:underline;
                color:blue;
                cursor:pointer;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            // show the given page, hide the rest
            function show(elementID) {
                // try to find the requested page and alert if it's not found
                var ele = document.getElementById(elementID);
                if (!ele) {
                    alert("no such element");
                    return;
                }

                // get all pages, loop through them and hide them
                var pages = document.getElementsByClassName('page');
                for(var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
                    pages[i].style.display = 'none';
                }

                // then show the requested page
                ele.style.display = 'block';
            }
            function pushButton(buttonValue) {
                if (buttonValue == 'C') {
                    document.getElementById('screen').value = '0';
                } else {//this is where most changes occured
                    var x= document.getElementById('screen').value 
                    x =parseInt(x)+ parseInt(buttonValue);
                    document.getElementById('screen').value=x;
                }
           }
           function calculate(equation) {
               var answer = eval(equation);
               document.getElementById('screen').value = answer;
           }
           function pushButton1(buttonValue) {
               if (buttonValue == 'd') {
                   document.getElementById('quantity').value = '0';
               } else {//this is where most changes occured
                   var x= document.getElementById('quantity').value 
                   x =parseInt(x)+ parseInt(buttonValue);
                   document.getElementById('quantity').value=x;
               }
           }
           function calculate(equation) {
              var answer = eval(equation);
              document.getElementById('quantity').value = answer;
           }
           function pushButton2(buttonValue) {
               if (buttonValue == 'd') {
                   document.getElementById('product').value = '0';
               } else {//this is where most changes occured
                   var x= document.getElementById('product').value 
                   x =parseInt(x)+ parseInt(buttonValue);
                   document.getElementById('product').value=x;
               }
           }
           function calculate(equation) {
               var answer = eval(equation);
               document.getElementById('product').value = answer;
           }
       </script>   
    </head>
    <body>
        <table class="calc" cellpadding=5> 
            <tr>
                <td colspan=3><input type="button" class="calc" id="screen" value="0" ></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><button type="button" onclick="pushButton(0);pushButton1(0);pushButton2(0);" value="Call2Functions">0</td>
                <td><button type="button" onclick="pushButton(1);pushButton1(1);pushButton2(1);" value="Call2Functions">1</td>
                <td><button type="button" onclick="pushButton(2);pushButton1(2);pushButton2(2);" value="Call2Functions">2</td>
                <td><button type="button" onclick="pushButton(3);pushButton1(3);pushButton2(3);" value="Call2Functions">3</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <form name="order" id="order">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="calc" id="product" value="0" ></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="calc" id="quantity" value="0" ></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here i have put some code which i took from references.when i click numbers it gets add in three places,but i want to add only in two places(third place should be empty). But when i click some button,the same button value should store in the place where it did not get store previously.

Comment: Your HTML is all over the place. You'll probably want to fix that before worrying about script. Multiple `head`, `html` `body` tags. A closing `div` tag after your closing `html` tag.. `tr` tags nested inside `td` tags? Use a validator or something. https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Comment: The fact that your "pages" use their own `html` / `body` / `script` tags, makes this html invalid in all the wrong ways.

Comment: Your HTML is very malformed. Is this one document, or multiple? If it is one, then before you address the JavaScript, you should review your HTML first. If it is all separate documents, please separate the documents into multiple code blocks for easier reading.

Comment: have a look here... http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Also, try to explain what you're trying to create here, that will help us understand your code better.

Comment: Basically, a single document should only have one `html` tag. Within that html tag should only be one `head` and one `body` tag. Your "pages" can be represented only within a `div` element. The fact that you have multiple `html` `head` and `body` tags will cause browser issues before any of your javascript issues.

Comment: now i have changed,In onClick i have added three functions so it executed in three place.but i want to execute in two place and third function should not run.if i add some button it should help me to run other two combination..

Comment: also this part of the code "document.getElementsByClassName('page');" seems rather empty after you deleted the div with the class="page". Try some tutorials from this millennium for both JavaScript and HTML.

Answer (score 0):

An html page is form like that :

```
<html> <!-- Open once -->
    <head> <!-- Open once -->
        <!-- All style and script here -->
        <title></title> <!-- Open once -->
    </head>

    <body> <!-- Open once -->
        <!-- Here your code, your <p>, table or <form> -->
    </body>

</html>
```

And a table looks like that :

```
<table>
    <tr> <!-- First row -->
        <td></td> <!-- First column -->
        <td></td> <!-- Second column -->
        <td></td> <!-- Third column -->
    </tr>

    <tr> <!-- Second row -->
        <td></td> <!-- First column -->
        <td></td> <!-- Second column -->
        <td></td> <!-- Third column -->
    </tr>
</table>
```

The problem is that your code is very bad formated. For example, you can't open `<html>` in an `<html>` or a `<body>` in a `<body>`

Comment: Thank you hearner,i am not worry about the structure i will change it later. If possible run this code.you will come to know what i exactly wanted